# Python: How to convert the integers in a string that's combined with integers and special characters to floats without changing the structure?

Tags: python

If I have a string like: `'2 5 3 $ # 2 ^ 1 4 !'` 
how can I format it to:  `'2.0 5.0 3.0 $ # 2.0 ^ 1.0 4.0 !'`?

What would be the most optimal way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @HeapOverflow It's just to fulfill a test case in which the results are required to be in floats for numerical values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the string, check each part to see if it's numeric - if so, make it into a float

```
in_string = '2 5 3 $ # 2 ^ 1 4 !'
out_string = ' '.join(str(float(x)) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in in_string.split())
print(out_string)
```

Output:

```
2.0 5.0 3.0 $ # 2.0 ^ 1.0 4.0 !
```

Answer (score 2):

One way could be using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and back-referencing the matches:

```
import re
s = '2 5 3 $ # 2 ^ 1 4 !'

re.sub(r'(\d)', r'\1.0', s)
# '2.0 5.0 3.0 $ # 2.0 ^ 1.0 4.0 !'
```